# Able to pull all but the last index from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created a Reddit bot that tracks information about a given post over a certain time period. I'm mapping that data with the library called `Chart.js`.

The information is stored  in a JSON file. Here's an example of the file containing two posts:

```
[
    {"time_scraped": ["2017-04-24 19:12:30", "2017-04-24 19:13:01", "2017-04-24 19:13:23"],
    "title": "Le Pen 'steps aside' as party leader",
    "downvotes": 0.0,
    "subreddit": "news",
    "post_id": "67b8ex",
    "vote": "up",
    "upvotes": [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]},

    {"time_scraped": ["2017-04-24 19:12:30", "2017-04-24 19:13:01", "2017-04-24 19:13:23"],
    "title": "10 Astronomical Events That Will Happen In Your Lifetime",
    "downvotes": 0.0,
    "subreddit": "videos",
    "post_id": "67b89w",
    "vote": "up",
    "upvotes": [2.0]}
]
```

A pretty standard JSON setup!

Right now, I'm using a bit of jQuery to pull data from this JSON file and inputting it into the DOM. That code, minus the portion where one creates the graph, looks like:

```
$.getJSON("./graph.json", function(json) {
    var list = [];
    var obj;
    for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
        obj = json[i]
        var name = "dataChart" + obj.post_id;
        var containerName = "graphContainer" + obj.post_id;
        $(".graphs").append("<div id='"+containerName+"'></div>");
        containerName = "#"+containerName;
        $(containerName).append("<canvas id='"+name+"'></canvas>");
        var ctx = document.getElementById(name);
        var dataChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            /*
                Create a graph...
            */
        });
    }
});
```

The `Create a graph...` section simply holds some data regarding the type of graph, point placement, etc. -- mostly option configurations, which I could show if need be. Which I find unimportant to this thread.

The problem arises with that jQuery code. It will cycle through just fine until the last post. For instance, out of the two posts above, it will create a container `div` and a `canvas` element for the first one, and display it fine. However, whenever it gets to the last array, it will simply create the container `div`, but not the `canvas` inside of it. This is the case for any number of graphs. If I had 20 arrays containing post data inside of my main JSON array, it would create 20 container `div`'s and only 19 `canvas`'s.

Am I looping through the data incorrectly?

Maybe it is still too early for me, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it isn't displaying the last index.

Comment: Well we can't find your problem. We don't have the exact response you're working with. You'll have to run through and place some trace code. `Console.log` your way through your code each step at a time. Log the index of the loop. Sometimes all you need is to see things visually to spot a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to iterate over an array and append multiple elements for each item

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const $graphs = $(".graphs");

data.forEach(d => {
  const $container = $(`<div class="container" id="${d}"><div class="canvas" id="${d}">I'm the ${d} canvas</div></div>`)

  $graphs.append($container)
})
```

```css
.container {
  background: orange;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.canvas {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graphs" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code does appear to create a canvas inside every div, at least with the JSON provided (and assuming Chart.js isn't messing around somehow).

For what it's worth, you can save yourself some DOM traversal (and a lot of possibly unnecessary element IDs) by keeping track of the elements you're creating instead of placing them in the document and then immediately looking them up again by their ID:

```js
var theJSON = [{
    "time_scraped": ["2017-04-24 19:12:30", "2017-04-24 19:13:01", "2017-04-24 19:13:23"],
    "title": "Le Pen 'steps aside' as party leader",
    "downvotes": 0.0,
    "subreddit": "news",
    "post_id": "67b8ex",
    "vote": "up",
    "upvotes": [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
  },

  {
    "time_scraped": ["2017-04-24 19:12:30", "2017-04-24 19:13:01", "2017-04-24 19:13:23"],
    "title": "10 Astronomical Events That Will Happen In Your Lifetime",
    "downvotes": 0.0,
    "subreddit": "videos",
    "post_id": "67b89w",
    "vote": "up",
    "upvotes": [2.0]
  }
];

//inlining the JSON for demo:
var theFunction = function(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    // "container" contains the DOM node to be appended to  .graphs:
    var container = $("<div id='graphContainer" + json[i].post_id + "'></div>")
      .appendTo($(".graphs"));
    // Now ctx can be appended directly to container, without a DOM lookup:
    var ctx = $("<canvas id='dataChart" + json[i].post_id + "'></canvas>")
      .appendTo(container);
    // and your chart can work directly with ctx, again with no DOM lookup required:
    /*
    var dataChart = new Chart(ctx, { ... });
    */
  }
};

theFunction(theJSON);
```

```css
/* Borders added so you can see what it's doing */
div {
  border: 2px solid #000
}

canvas {
  border: 2px solid #F00
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="graphs"></div>
```